# How do I allow a self closing tag in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

The source tags inside my video element need to be self closing so the iPad doesn't start whinging.

I type in `<source src="myVideo.m4v" />`

TinyMCE keeps changing it to `<source src="myVideo.m4v" ></source>` though.

How can I tell it to stop?

Comment: As last resort you can always change it back before sending it away: data = data.Replace("></source>", " />");

Comment: thanks for that but yeah my preference lies away from last resorts generally

Comment: I agree it would be nice to not use a hacky solution, but I'm having trouble with using the <plug:plugin_name /> tags that come with indexhibit. I'd like them to work. I'll ask a seperate question about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [valid_elements](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/valid_elements) and [extended_valid_elements.](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/extended_valid_elements)

**EDIT:**

You may use the closed setting in your tinymce init:

```
closed : /^(br|hr|input|meta|img|link|param|area)$/, // default
```

to

```
closed: /^(br|hr|input|meta|img|link|param|area|source)$/,
```

If this does not work then i think you might additionaly need to change one line of code from the tinymce core code located in Editor.js on line 2666 (newest tiny mce version) and extend the setting there with your source tag.

Comment: I have done. I've added everything I need. It is allowing my source tag but it is not allowing it to be self closing

Comment: Thanks! Just so you know it worked without having to edit the core code