# TinyMCE removes youtube links

Tags: html, symfony1, tinymce, sanitization

I've got a symfony form with a "contents" textarea, which uses tinyMCE.

When I write :

```
<p class="centre">
<object width="640" height="385">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/qOP2V_np2c0&hl=en_US&fs=1&rel=0">
</param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
</param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
</param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/qOP2V_np2c0&hl=en_US&fs=1&rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385">
</embed>
</object>
</p>
```

It gets saved as :

```
<p class="centre">
<object width="640" height="385">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/qOP2V_np2c0&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
</object>
</p>
```

Comment: have you checked this with firebug? Because it sometimes corrects invalid html automatically. Make sure this really is the html you're getting, by using the "view source" method, or wget.

Comment: Even before saving, tinymce removes that html. So it's not symfony's fault, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add some elements to *extended_valid_elements* so that it wouldn't remove flash content.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : “textareas”,
    editor_selector:“mceEditor”,
    theme : “advanced”,
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : “bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,code”,
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : “”,theme_advanced_buttons3 : “”,theme_advanced_buttons4 : “”,
    theme_advanced_resizing : true, tab_focus : “:prev,:next”,
    extended_valid_elements : “object[width|height|classid|codebase],param[name|value],embed[src|type|width|height|flashvars|wmode]“
});
```

Answer found on http://syedgakbar.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/adding-flash-embed-support-in-tinymce-editor/

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `param` tag inside the `closed` key of your `init` config array:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    closed: /^(br|hr|input|meta|img|link|param|area|param)$/,
    ...
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080132/how-do-i-allow-a-self-closing-tag-in-tinymce)

Comment: Well I may have a bug somewhere, but if I remove the second line, html code gets stripped from the contents field

Comment: did you use the constant "ESC_RAW" as a parameter of the `getContents` method?

Comment: nope.But I found that the removing of html was tinyMCE's doing, not symfony

Comment: some of it might be tinymces doing, some might be browser related. browsers will try to "fix" invalid html like not-closed tags

Comment: Well, if it's related to TinyMCE and not symfony, you may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080132/how-do-i-allow-a-self-closing-tag-in-tinymce) interesting. Just add the `param` tag in the `closing` options inside your `init`.